# Where to instanciate adapters in hexagonal architecture

Tags: hexagonal-architecture

I am building a simple application with the trying to follow best practices with hexagonal architecture.
My main entry point is my manual dependency injection starter, I usually considered this code as the application part but I have to instanciate adapters creating a hard coupling between adapters and the application part breaking the dependency rule.
So where should I instanciate the adapters manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's effectively a layer coupling problem.

I think, you can put your starter in the  `Adapter's layer` in your hexagone because your hex should be free of knowledge of `Adapters` implementation.

You can also put your starter at the root of your source code or in a low level configuration part of the app.

In addition, think of automatic injection (like `CDI` in Java).

Comment: My bad, I was wrongly mixing DDD with hexagonal concepts. I will try to reformulate the question.

Comment: I re-write my answer.

Comment: Ok, it's less intuitive but I think is the best solution. The CDI I think only hide the problem. But thinking in main as an adapter can help to structure the application and the diferent configurations better. Thank you.